# GraphQL mutation or query, how to target specific site?

Tags: multi-site, graphql

Is there a restriction on graphQL that only allows it to work on the primary site?

My system has for unknown reason switched primary (and I can't change it back due to a bug), and ever since then my graphQL mutation fails claiming there is no such entry (switching primary in my dev env fizes the problem).

I figured that the base URL of the api request controlled which site it was querying, but that doesn't seem to be the case either?

I'm using the mutation `save_sectionHandle_entryTypeHandle_Entry()`. The ID I send in seems to be the same across different sites, so I need some way to distinguish between them to edit the right entry it seems, or in my case, allowing the call to even find the entry...

Answer (score 1):

Aha, it was merely sending in `siteId` as well when updating, in addition to `id`. If siteId is missing, it will default to primary site it seems.